# 'Uncaught Error: DATA_CLONE_ERR: DOM Exception 25' thrown by web worker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, web-worker

So I'm creating a web worker:

```
var arrayit = function(obj) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(obj);
};
work = arrayit(images);
console.log(work);
//work = images.push.apply( images, array );
// Method : "load+scroll"
var worker = new Worker('jail_worker.js');
worker.postMessage(work)
worker.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log("Worker said:" + event.data);
};
```

Here's what images is:

```
$.jail.initialStack = this;
// Store the selector into 'triggerEl' data for the images selected
this.data('triggerEl', (options.selector) ? $(options.selector) : $window);
var images = this;
```

I think my problem has something to do with this:

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#safe-passing-of-structured-data

How can I get around this?  as you can see, I tried slicing the host object into a real array, but that didn't work.

Here's a link to the file I'm hacking on:

https://github.com/jtmkrueger/JAIL

UPDATE--------------------------------------------------

This is what I had to do based on the accepted answer from @davin:

```
var arrayit = function(obj) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(obj);
};
imgArray = arrayit(images);
work = _.map(images, function(i){ return i.attributes[0].ownerElement.outerHTML; });

var worker = new Worker('jail_worker.js');
worker.postMessage(work)
worker.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log("Worker said:" + event.data);
};
```

NOTE: I used underscore.js to assure compatibility.

Comment: As an aside, have you considered alternatives to this method for async/parallel image/content distribution? A CDN, subdomain splits, a RequireJS plugin, etc.?

Comment: yes, and some of those things are already happening.

Comment: Well be aware that over parallelising is usually more of a performance drag than an enhancement, so if you're already implementing things and they aren't good enough, maybe you should see how well those are working...

Comment: this is the only aspect I have scope to control, so I'm trying to make the best of it.

Comment: Too bad. What host object are you talking about? What exactly are you trying to pass to the WW? If you're looking to pass the jquery object that won't work since WW API doesn't implement shared memory, and trying to copy an Object results in passing an empty object (as your link explained). You need to serialise any data you wan't to send across.

Comment: isn't that what my arrayit method is doing?  I think your on to something there...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3676/discussion-between-jtmkrueger-and-davin)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The original exception was most likely thrown because you tried passing a host object to the web worker (most likely a dom element). Your subsequent attempts don't throw the same error. Remember two key points: there isn't shared memory between the different threads, and the web workers can't manipulate the DOM.

`postMessage` supports passing structured data to threads, and will [internally serialise](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Worker#postMessage%28%29) (or in some other way copy the *value* of the data recursively) the data. Serialising DOM elements often results in circular reference errors, so your best bet is to `map` the object you want serialised and extract relevant data to be rebuilt in the web worker.

Comment: Well explained and to the point. Thank you, saved me a lot of hours of reading.

Comment: postMessage cloning algorithm support cyclic structures

Answer (score 0):

`Uncaught DataCloneError: An object could not be cloned` was reproduced when tried save to indexeddb function as object's key. Need double recheck that saved object is serializable