# Web worker dealing with imageData working with Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, web-worker

When I run code that deals with imageData being passed to a web worker and then back, then Firefox works great but Chrome gives "Uncaught Error: DATA_CLONE_ERR: DOM Exception 25"

Searching google suggests that older versions of Chrome used to work?

I checked some more and it seemed as if I needed to run JSON.stringify and JSON.parse on the imagedata before sending it but then it stops working everywhere. The code that works in FF 9 is:

image.js:

```
var myImageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
var worker = new Worker("http://direct.link/helpers/worker.js");
worker.postMessage(myImageData);  
worker.onmessage = function(event) {
  var value = event.data;
  switch (value.cmd){
    case 'last':
      //doing stuff 
      break;
  default:
      //doing stuff
    });
}
```

worker.js:

```
addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  var myImageData = event.data;
  // doing stuff.
  sendItBack(colors);
});
};

    function sendItBack(colors){
    each(colors, function(index, value){
      self.postMessage(value);
    }); 
    self.postMessage({'cmd': 'last'});
    }
```

What method should I use in order to send this imagedata back and forth the app and the web worker?

Thanks!

EDIT:

If I copy to a regular array then Chrome starts working...

```
var newImageData = [];
for (var i=0,len=myImageData.length;i<len;++i) newImageData[i] = myImageData[i];
```

So chrome can't pass a CanvasPixelArray to a worker but it can pass a regular Array. But firefox can.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506635/uncaught-error-data-clone-err-dom-exception-25-thrown-by-web-worker

Comment: oops. Thanks. Let me try that :)

Comment: I'm still not clear about this. The data that I'm passing ( context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data ) is a large array and should not have any circular reference errors. If it is being converted to JSON internally by postMessage then it should just go through with out errors. And as far as I know, I'm not forwarding a DOM element.

Comment: I get this error too, but not if I try to pass the whole ImageData object instead of the ImageData.data. Mapping a CanvasPixelArray to a regular array seems like it could be a waste of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this as follow up. I can reproduce your error in case anyone else can answer your question (I can't unfortunately). I've searched the Chromium issues to see if it's an outstanding bug, but not found anything. Given image processing is one of the more popular uses of WebWorkers I would hope someone can answer you quickly.

http://jsfiddle.net/gGFSJ/9/

From Chrome (asterisks added by me):

```
window.URL does not exist
window.WebKitURL does not exist
using window.webkitURL for URL
window.BlobBuilder does not exist
using window.WebKitBlobBuilder for BlobBuilder
***Uncaught Error: DATA_CLONE_ERR: DOM Exception 25***
data=send back.
data=to worker.
data=send back.
data=0.
```

From Firefox:

```
using window.URL for URL
window.BlobBuilder does not exist
window.WebKitBlobBuilder does not exist
window.webkitBlobBuilder does not exist
using window.MozBlobBuilder for BlobBuilder
data=send back.
data=to worker.
data=send back.
data=0.
data=send back.
data=[object Uint8ClampedArray].
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this! This uses similar code: http://dylanfm.github.com/Ladderfck/ ( https://github.com/garg/Ladderfck/blob/master/javascripts/app.js ) and it works just fine on Chrome but I'm not sure why mine isn't working. Thanks again

Comment: Marked as the answer because your original comment was correct but now I understand. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6):

What I do is pass the entire imagedata object from the context to the worker, and not just the data:

```
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// This works beautifully
worker.postMessage({imgData:imgData});

// But this throws the exception
worker.postMessage({imgData:imgData.data});
```

With this approach you're passing a few extra attributes to the worker (namely, the array's width and height), but I think this bit of extra data is better than the overhead associated with copying the entire data array.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. In current chrome (v33), passing the entire ImageData object works.

Answer (score 1):

If I copy the **getimagedata.data** array to a regular array and then pass the array to a webworker then Chrome starts working.

```
var newImageData = [];
for (var i=0,len=myImageData.length;i<len;++i) newImageData[i] = myImageData[i];
```

So chrome can't pass a **CanvasPixelArray** to a worker but it can pass a regular Array. But Firefox can pass an **imagedata.data** directly.

Comment: Shame you can't seem to do it directly like in FF. Maybe Chrome's CanvasPixelArray has some link to the DOM, or maybe Chrome is just being over-cautious with the data it allows to be passed through.